# How to implement two way communication with gRpc?

Tags: c#, wcf, grpc

For various reasons, over the years the company I work for have invested considerably into using Windows Communication Foundation (WCF). We are currently in the process of upgrading our main development platform from Visual Studio 2015 to Visual Studio 2022. Sadly, we are discovering that our WCF client and server applications need more work than we expected to upgrade them to Visual Studio 2022 and newer .NET frameworks; they certainly are not as slick as they used to be. We are planning on keeping our existing applications that use WCF as they are but are considering other options for new applications. The main option that seems to be the one being pushed is gRpc, however, from what I have learnt about it so far, for some of the kinds of things we want to do, it would seem to be a very poor substitute. For us some of the key things we value in WCF are:

- One way function calls (i.e. a call that so long as we know gets
  delivered, we do not need to wait until it completes). I understand
  that this is achievable with gRpc.
- Full two way communication (i.e.
  clients can make calls onto the server, and also the other way
  around; the server can make calls onto the clients). I understand
  that using “streams” this can be approximated to with gRPC, but not
  easily.

To illustrate, consider a simplified scenario involving three application types:

- Sound Requester. An application that requests the playing of different sounds at different locations, and also change the sound parameters.
- Sound Player. An application that can play requested sounds and change their parameters. It can give notification that a sound has finished.
- Sound Handler Proxy. An application that sits between sound requesters and sound players.

Our WCF implementation of this has the Sound Handler Proxy as the WCF server, the Sound Requester and Sound Player applications are clients that connect to the server. This suits us nicely; the proxy does not need to know which players and requesters to connect to, they connect to it (and can do so at any time). The proxy just provides a ‘marshalling’ service. Below is a simplified sequence diagram to illustrate the kind of calls that could be made:

[image]

My question is “If implementing this using gRpc, how would we implement the calls on SoundPlayer (e.g. CreateSound, PlaySound etc.)?” If my understanding is correct, since SoundPlayer is a client (not a server), we would need to implement these as streams that come as ‘returns’ from a call from the player to the server. Is there an easier way? (I appreciate that we could make the SoundPlayer a server that the SoundHandlerProxy could connect to as a client – but that would mean the proxy would need to know about all the players it is going to connect to, something we would rather avoid.)
Alternatively, is there something other than gRpc that we could migrate to (preferably, something that is going to be stable for at least the next decade)?

Comment: Not totally sure if this is what you're after, but check out [the `Racer` example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/tree/master/examples) on the grpc-dotnet GitHub. It's for a web app, but the principle of sending bidirectional messages should still apply.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewWatson. I have taken a look at the example you pointed me to. I think that it is roughly the approach that I have reached myself so far - i.e. using streams. My problem with this is that I need my server (SoundHandlerProxy) to be able to call a number of different functions on the client (SoundPlayer). In which case I would need to set up a number of different streams or use a single stream but build in some way to say which "function" I want the client to perform. Both possible, but far from the ease with which it could be done with WCF. Your input is appreciated though.

Comment: The function you want to implement is similar to the server can call the function on the client side, the client can choose to execute the method, and the language is specified to use c#. Is my understanding  in line with your idea?

Comment: In your current WCF application, you are specifically using the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/one-way-services and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/duplex-services approaches?

Comment: Hello @EricAnderson, my apologies for a slow response -- I have been away. To answer your questions: (1) Yes, we are using "IsOneWay=true" for the one way function calls. We can determine that the function call got delivered, but other than that we get no response to the function call (which is fine for our case). (2) Yes, we are using the "CallbackContract". Other information: we are using the NetTcpBinding (with ReliableSession Enabled and Ordered set) usually, occasionally the NetNamedPipeBinding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a .Net expert, so I may get some details wrong. But I think the gist is right.

[**One-way services**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/one-way-services) aren't all that interesting on-the-wire, as they are still use HTTP request/response. From the [One-Way Sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/one-way)

> When the operation is called, the service returns an HTTP status code of 202 before the service operation has executed... The client that called the operation blocks until it receives the 202 response from the service.

So they are more of a stub feature and can be emulated without too much trouble in gRPC. In gRPC, you'd define the method to return `google.protobuf.Empty`, and on server-side start long-running work in another thread and return immediately.

```
service Foo {
  rpc Bar(BarRequest) returns (google.protobuf.Empty);
}
```

```cs
public class FooService : Foo.FooBase
{
    public override Task<Empty> Bar(BarRequest request,
        ServerCallContext context)
    {
        startProcessingInAnotherThread(request);
        return Task.FromResult(new Empty {});
    }
}
```

**Full two way communication** seems to be the same as [Duplex Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/duplex-services). These work by configuring the client to know how the server can reach it (its host:port). Then the client sends that information to the server for the server send RPCs back to it in the future. There are definitely security impacts of such a design and you should look into the security model you are using.

This would be emulated in gRPC by the client just sending the server a channel address string and then the server creating a channel to that address.

```
service SoundHandler {
  rpc Connect(ConnectRequest) returns (google.protobuf.Empty);
}

message ConnectRequest {
  enum Type {
    TYPE_UNKNOWN = 0;
    TYPE_SOUND_REQUESTER = 1;
    TYPE_SOUND_PLAYER = 2;
  };

  string channelAddress = 1;
  Type type = 2;
}

service SoundPlayer {
  rpc CreateSound(CreateSoundRequest) returns (CreateSoundResponse);
  // ...
}

service SoundEventReceiver {
  rpc SoundFinished(SoundFinishedRequest) returns (SoundFinishedResponse);
}
```

Then, in the service you'd create a channel to the provided address for callbacks.

```cs
public class SoundHandlerService : SoundHandler.SoundHandlerBase
{
    public override Task<Empty> Bar(ConnectRequest request,
        ServerCallContext context)
    {
        var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(request.channelAddress);
        if (request.type == TYPE_SOUND_PLAYER) {
          var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(request.channelAddress);
          var client = new SoundPlayer.SoundPlayerClient(channel);
          registerSoundPlayer(channel, client);
        } // ...
        return Task.FromResult(new Empty {});
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Eric, thanks for the response. I agree that one way calls are easy to be emulated as you suggest, thanks. As for the duplex (two way communication); I understand your suggestion to be that the "clients" in effect set up their own service for the return calls that the "server" can call back on. Is that a correct interpretation of your answer?

Comment: One thing to mention Eric, concerning the security you mention. The scenario we have in mind is a set of machines on a dedicated network completely disconnected from the internet (and every other network). I appreciate that this does not mean that I can ignore security, but it does reduce the risk considerably.

Comment: Just thinking about the emulation of the one-way call; there is a slight problem in that if the call is not delivered for whatever reason, the call site (in terms of 'the logical' call site, as opposed to how it is emulated) the does not get notification of the failure. With a bit of effort that can be worked around I guess.

Comment: 1) '"clients" in effect set up their own service for the return calls that the "server" can call back on.' Yes, that is what I was suggesting. That is the same as what .Net is doing under-the-hood. 2) Yeah, security is probably fine. The important thing was to just consider it and think about how the current system's security was preserved. 3) I don't understand what case causes the "call is not delivered". For network failures, the RPC would fail.