# Remove network hops for service calls

Tags: grpc

I tried to check if there is a way to reduce the number of hops between services under the asumption that the contract is compatible and the same between Client and ServiceN below.
In this case "Client" is not thought of as an outside party but part of the backend solution.

The flow as I usually see it:

Request: Client -> Service1 -> Service2 -> ... -> ServiceN

Response: ServiceN -> ... -> Service2 -> Service1 -> Client

What I am looking for is this:

Request:
Client -> Service1 -> Service2 -> ... -> ServiceN

Response: ServiceN -> Client

Or in other words, I want to reuce the number of networks hops in the response, in this case it just relays the same answer back all the way from ServiceN to Client.

Can I achieve this through some config in gRPC or is it not possible?

Thanks for any feedback :-)

**EDIT for clarification:**
I used to work with a system that did this with UDP and we ended up reducing latency.

The solution for us was to secure the backend through firewalls and only have very few open entrypoints with secured channels that drives the actual internal service calls.

The natural solution is to know exectly what each and every service call is supposed to be done at all times and just go one hop, but this was not always possible due to required data aggregation running through specific nodes with specialized hardware for a couple of requests.

There are of course some drawbacks.
Named services, especially the clients, are more coupled to the server calls than to just go to call a single node and wait for a response. It is highly asynchronous on the client side as well so it's usually a "fire and forget" request with all that it entails to ensure some stability in the response.

Additionally the responsibility of who to answer is a bit more involved on the server-response side.

The advantage was pretty substantial in this case since we simply cut all latency by shortcutting all response hops.

Please note that with "clients" here I do not mean a final endpoints (i.e. a computer outside the backend system). A client here resides entirely inside the backend.

It could be interesting to establish a server-to-client stream channel for a server response on some node connections. Maybe that is what I can do to use gRPC instead. This will however require a more or less permanent channel for responses for each node in question or I will simply pay too much for the handshaking. The advantage of the UDP protocol here is that it's implicitly more scalable w.r.t. response.

Maybe I can write a specialized service that works through gRPC but performs the final response through a custom UDP+protobuf payload call. That I guess will be a hybrid.

This is most likely too specific for a gRPC implementation but just want to see if someone has worked with similar issues. Thanks for the feedback so far and any response is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's not intrinsically possible.

gRPC is a remote procedure call mechanism and request-response.

So, in your flow, you have...

Requests:

```
Client client       --> Service1 server
...
Service(N-1) client --> ServiceN server
```

Responses:

```
ServiceN server     --> Service(N-1) client
...
Service1 server     --> Client client
```

The only way for `ServiceN` server to send a message directly to `Client` is for `ServiceN` client (!) to call a method on the `Client` server (!) and this would require that incoming requests (!) include the endpoint of the `Client`'s server, i.e.

Requests (!):

```
ServerN client      --> Client server
```

This adds complexity, not only in the unusual flow but in your system then needing to be able to reconcile the original client requests to the request (!) its companion server receives.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74366118/4690866 has an example of what that direct server → client communication would look like. But I do agree it is very unusual. It is most likely to happen _within_ a service, e.g., to manage which shard has data, and not be exposed to generic clients.